# FPDF: Error 404

Tags: php, hosting, fpdf

En el sistema web se encuentra un botón para generar el PDF, al presionarlo abre una nueva pestaña que muestra ''Oops, looks like the page is lost.
This is not a fault, just an accident that was not intentional.''

En la consola se muestra: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () + la ruta del archivo PHP con el que se genera el PDF.

Esto solo sucede cuando el sistema está en subido en el host, en local funciona perfecto.

Comment: Te dice que no encuentra la ruta... tienes bien configurada la ruta a donde ir a buscar el archivo en tu host?

Comment: si, me muestra la ruta correcta donde se localiza el archivo

Comment: Los errores 404 significan que ese recurso no existe en esa ruta. Debes verificar la ruta y/o que el recurso existe ahí, por más que pienses que es correcta no lo es. Un error no significa otra cosa que recurso no encontrado.

Comment: Revisa el .htaccess, seguro el problema viene de ahí.